# Can I delete value in loaderinfo.parameters object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Flash gives access to query-string parameters via calling `loaderInfo.parameters()` method.

And I couldn't delete the field on the object. IS it possible to delete some fields in the object? If possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete/modify anything in parameters property of loaderInfo object, because it is read-only (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#parameters)
What you can do is to write your own wrapper of the loaderInfo.parameters and decide what exactly to show and what not.

`public class Wrapper {`

```
private var _mySetting:String;

public function Wrapper(stage:Stage) {
    var parameters:Object = stage.loaderInfo.parameters;
    _mySetting = parameters.mySetting;
}
public function get mySetting():String {
    if(... your condition here ...) {
        return _mySetting;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

}